# React render() without html tags?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

Why can't I do this in react?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    somefun() {
        return (<p>hello</p>);
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
            {somefun()}
        )
    }
 }
```

When I try I get a compile error

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\karln\baeldung\my-app\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "{" (9:13)

   7 |  render() {
   8 |          return (
>  9 |                  {somefun()}
     |                            ^
  10 |          )
  11 |  }
  12 |  }
```

I'm new to react and getting through, but this one kind of vexes me.

Comment: You can use JSX in other functions. The problem here is that the brackets can only be used inside of the JSX tree. You can either eliminate the brackets completely, or wrap them into a JSX element: `return (<div>{someFun()}</div>)`

Comment: I saw that I could do `(<div>{somefun()}</div>)` but I thought that was messy. What is `<>{somefun()}<>` and what does it do? I assume that would not generate any html other than what is produced by `somefun` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root element

```
<> </>
```

or

`React.Fragment` or whatever the tag is

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `React.Fragment` ? Would that be instead of `React.Component` ?

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's longhand for `<> </>`.

Comment: Yes it is, to be honest i prefer longhand, it's way more clean

Comment: @SullivanTobias What is the definition of "clean" here?

Comment: Yes I should have been clearer

I should say that in a context where the render is not super long you can use the shorthand

But I find that when there are many more elements, I find the longhand much more meaningful.

In the end I only use longhand now for comprehension reasons.

But everyone has their own way of doing things in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<> {somefun()} </>
```

This is React Fragment. It does not write any html tags like div, p...

Answer (score 0):

`{}` isn't valid there. It's used to interpolate values in JSX (like `<h1>{title}</h1>`) but you aren't in a JSX element there.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

*You need a root element first*

```
render(){
return(
<div>
{somefun()}
</div>
)}
```